# JavaScript - how to pass variable through a function from loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

here's what i try to accomplish

- when user click div class='container' it will alert the innerHTML of his spesific child
  (p class='primary_key' )
- no JQuery

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .primary_key{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="primary_key">1</p>
            <p class="content">content1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="primary_key">2</p>
            <p class="content">content2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
    window.onload = function(){

    var allContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
    for(var i=0; i<allContainer.length; i++){
        var container =  allContainer[i];
        allContainer[i].onclick = function(e){
            clickContainer(container);
        }
    }
}

function clickContainer(ele){
    var selectedId = ele.getElementsByClassName('primary_key')[0].innerHTML;
    alert(selectedId);
}
```

it supposed to

- when user click first container it will show/alert 1
- when user click second container it will show/alert 2

but my code always alert = 2

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iliketo/2CRp6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
allContainer[i].onclick = function(e){
    clickContainer(this);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason this is happening is because the for loop is changing the `container` so when the element is clicked it should alert 2 either way because `container` is the last container, you can use a closure like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < allContainer.length; i++){
    (function(container){
        container.onclick = function(e){
            clickContainer(container);
        }
    })(allContainer[i]);
}
```

This "captures" the container in a function

Or event better you can remove everything out of your `for` loop, like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < allContainer.length; i++){
     clickContainer(allContainer[i])
}

function clickContainer(element){
    element.onclick = function() {
        var selectedId = this.getElementsByClassName('primary_key')[0].innerHTML;
        alert(selectedId);
    }
}
```

I would also recommend `addEventListener('click', handler)` over `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
var allContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
for(var i=0; i<allContainer.length; i++)
{
    var container =  allContainer[i];
    if (typeof window.addEventListener === 'function'){
        (function (e) {
            container.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log(e);
                clickContainer(e);
            });
        })(container);
    }
}
```

Actually you need to wrap the assignment of the event listener in a closure.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2CRp6/1/)